# ConTeXt: blank vertical space before and after defineframed

Tags: context

I am trying to define a framed environment (if that's the right term) that is essentially a box with some space before and after it. I can't to figure out an idiomatic way to automatically add space before and after it.

This is a skeleton of what I have:

```
%&context

\defineframed
  [Callout]
  [offset=1em]

\starttext

I want an automatic space after this paragraph.

\Callout{There is no space above or below the frame}

I want an automatic space before this paragraph.

\stoptext
```

I found the `top` and `bottom` options, but these add space within the frame, rather than around it. I might be missing something, but can't find something like `before` and `after` on the wiki ([setupframed](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupframed)).

I've been able to add some space using `\prependvalue{Callout}{\blank[big]}`, but this does not seem idiomatic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from your short example I assume that you are looking for `framedtext` rather than `framed`.  That one supports `before` and `after`.

```
\defineframedtext
  [Callout]
  [offset=1em,
   width=fit,
   before={\blank[big]},
   after={\blank[2*big]}]

\starttext

I want an automatic space after this paragraph.

\startCallout
  There is no space above or below the frame
\stopCallout

I want an automatic space before this paragraph.

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

If you, for whatever reason, don't like the `\start...\stopCallout` variant and rather want to use `\Callout{...}` and keep the space before and after, just overwrite the definition of `\Callout`.

```
\starttexdefinition unexpanded singleempty Callout [#1]#2
  \startCallout[#1]#2\stopCallout
\stoptexdefinition
```

Comment: In case anyone else runs into the same issue as I had, note the use of `\startCallout` and `\stopCallout` with the `\defineframedtext`. I had initially tried to use `\Callout{}` with `\defineframedtext`, the same way as with `\defineframed` and the `before/after` arguments did not behave as expected.

Comment: @ssokolen This is because they use different mechanisms.  `\startCallout` invokes `\pack_framed_text_start` whereas `\Callout` uses `\pack_framed_text_direct`.  The direct version has `\blank[disable]` inside of it.