# ConTeXt: Add exterior padding to framedtext

Tags: context, metapost

## Background

Looking to adjust the exterior padding of a METAPOST graphic used as the background for a framedtext.

ConTeXt version 2021.05.15.

## SSCCE

Pilfered from the mailing list:

```tex
\startuseMPgraphic{TextBubble}
  z1 = (0, 0) ;
  z2 = (OverlayWidth, 0) ;
  z3 = (OverlayWidth, OverlayHeight) ;
  z4 = (0, OverlayHeight) ;

  2/12[x1,x2] = x8 + 1cm = x7 + .5cm = x9 - .5cm ;
  y7 =  0cm ;
  y8 = -1cm ;
  y9 =  0cm ;

  path p ;
  p = (z1--z7--z8--z9--z2--z3--z4--cycle) cornered .25cm ;
  draw p withpen pencircle scaled 0.5 ;

  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[TextBubbleOverlay][\useMPgraphic{TextBubble}]
\defineframedtext[TextBubbleFrame][
  frame=off,
  width=\textwidth,
  background=TextBubbleOverlay,
  offset=.5em,
]

\starttext 
  \input knuth

  \TextBubbleFrame{\input ward \input knuth }

  \input knuth
\stoptext
```

## Problem

The speech bubble dips into the text below:

[image: speech bubble]

The `after` option appears to be ignored and `boffset` will increase the overall height.

## Questions

How would you add enough padding so that the tail is on a line or two by itself? Is there a way to increase the METAPOST graphic height such that the framed text honours the new size?

Using something like `\define\PaddedBubble{\TextBubble{...}\blank[1cm]}` would work, but doesn't feel like *The ConTeXt Way*. (Can't use [Speech Bubble](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/index.php?title=Speech_bubble) module because it isn't guaranteed to be installed.)

## Related

Similar issues:

- [ConTeXt: blank vertical space before and after defineframed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387114/context-blank-vertical-space-before-and-after-defineframed)

Comment: You need to use the `\start ... \stop ...` variant: https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg87403.html. Btw, aren't text backgrounds a better alternative? They should work as fine as framed texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution isn't the greatest: the tail height is coupled to the `3*big`, indirectly, rather than linked using an option or variable.

```tex
\startuseMPgraphic{TextBubble}
  z1 = (0, 0) ;
  z2 = (OverlayWidth, 0) ;
  z3 = (OverlayWidth, OverlayHeight) ;
  z4 = (0, OverlayHeight) ;

  2/12[x1,x2] = x8 + 1cm = x7 + .5cm = x9 - .5cm ;
  y7 =  0cm ;
  y8 = -1cm ;
  y9 =  0cm ;

  path p ;
  p = (z1--z7--z8--z9--z2--z3--z4--cycle) cornered .25cm ;
  draw p withpen pencircle scaled 0.5 ;

  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[TextBubbleOverlay][\useMPgraphic{TextBubble}]
\defineframedtext[TextBubbleFrame][
  frame=off,
  width=\textwidth,
  background=TextBubbleOverlay,
  offset=.5em,
  after={\blank[3*big]},
]

\starttext 
  \input knuth

  \startTextBubbleFrame
    \input ward
  \stopTextBubbleFrame

  \input knuth
\stoptext
```

I could not get text backgrounds to work. It looks like text background requires iterating over the number of rows in the paragraph.

[image: speech bubble]